# ListView Error while loading activity

Tags: android, mysql, listview, android-intent

My listview is causing error when i try to open below listview activity using intent action.
I have checked manifest and it is perfectly correct , idk may be there is some problem in code .Please help

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    JSONArray jArray;
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null; 
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    String targetmonth;

    int responseCode;
    int listItemCount=0;
    ListView listview ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        new LoadData().execute();

         // listening to single list item on click
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {

              // selected item
              String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

              // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
              Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
              // sending data to new activity
              i.putExtra("product", product);
              startActivity(i);

          }
        });


    } 



    private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>   { 
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;  
        @Override
        // can use UI thread here
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "","Loading...");  
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {  
            try{

                     listview.setAdapter(new DataAdapter(MainActivity.this,al.toArray(new String[al.size()])));


                     this.progressDialog.dismiss();





                }
                catch(Exception e){ 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }  
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            // HTTP post 
                    try { 
                        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
                        try{
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.0.1/app/ap.php");

                        StringEntity se = new StringEntity("envelope",HTTP.UTF_8);
                        httppost.setEntity(se); 
                        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
                        int timeoutConnection = 3000;
                        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
                        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
                        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
                        int timeoutSocket = 3000;
                        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket); 

                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        is = entity.getContent(); 
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        //buffered reader
                        try{
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                is, "iso-8859-1"), 80);
                        sb = new StringBuilder();
                        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                        String line = "0";
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        is.close();
                        result = sb.toString();


                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        try{
                        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                        JSONObject json_data = null;
                        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
                            //targetamount=json_data.getString("targetamount");
                            targetmonth=json_data.getString("targetmonth");
                            //targetyear = json_data.getString("targetyear"); 
                            al.add(targetmonth); 
                            //al1.add(targetyear);
                            //al2.add(targetamount);  

                            //listItemCount=al2.size();
                        }
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }   
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                    //  Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }  
                     catch (Exception e) {
                            //  Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }       


            return null; 
        }


    }
```

//Data Adapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView; 
public class DataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mContext; 
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    String targetmonth;
    String[] month;

    public DataAdapter(Context c, String[] month) {
        this.month = month;

        mContext = c;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c); 
    } 
    public int getCount() {
        return month.length;
    } 
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    } 
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    } 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customgrid, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.month = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.targetmonth); 

            if (position == 0) {
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        try {

            holder.month.setText(month[position]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return convertView;
    } 
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView month;

    }

}
```

//SingleListItem will open and show selected item when onclick listview

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SingleListItem extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.meter);

        TextView txtProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_label);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        // getting attached intent data
        String product = i.getStringExtra("product");
        // displaying selected product name
        txtProduct.setText(product);

    }
}



    }
```

//logcat error

```
05-20 11:36:04.443: I/dalvikvm(856):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 11:36:04.453: D/AndroidRuntime(856): Shutting down VM
05-20 11:36:04.453: W/dalvikvm(856): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.status.what/com.cat.what.Fun}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.cat.what.Fun.onCreate(Fun.java:63)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  ... 11 more
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  ... 23 more
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1937)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2780)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:385)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:174)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:170)
05-20 11:36:04.503: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  ... 26 more
```

//xml file main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/bin"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="1">

     <ListView
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:id="@+id/listView1"  
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:clickable="true"
          android:background="@drawable/bin"
          android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
          android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"          
          android:dividerHeight="5sp"
          android:listSelector="@drawable/selector"
          android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
          android:padding="15sp"
          >

     </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

// custom grid

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent">
       <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content">
       </TableRow>
      <LinearLayout 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:weightSum="1">
           <TextView 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:text="hello" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:id="@+id/targetmonth" 
               android:textSize="15sp"
               android:textStyle="italic"
               android:paddingBottom="5sp" 
               android:paddingRight="5sp" 
               android:paddingTop="5sp" 
               android:layout_gravity="left" 
               android:layout_weight="0.32" 
               android:gravity="left|center" 
               android:paddingLeft="10sp" 
               android:textColor="#ffc844">

           </TextView>
       </LinearLayout>

</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add your xml file here

Comment: done you can check now

Comment: not this one dude your LazyAdapter Xml

Comment: and yes dont inflate your baseadapter view to from context. instend you get layout inflatore service and there are also memory out of bound prob. so check your images size.

Comment: i am beginner , not exact idea about that and i have not placed images yet in listview and i have mentioned main.xml contain listview and textview as customgrid.xml

Comment: its fixed , it has error in xml thanks for listening